# How can I export the parts of an image while preserving the relative width in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg, export

How can I export the parts of an image while preserving the relative width in Inkscape?

I have a ladder. It consists out of four parts. I export each part as a `.png`. Now, when viewed inside the Inkscape the ladder parts match just fine. But after export the width of the bottom part of the ladder does not match the width of the penultimate (counting from the top) part. How could I fix it?

I am attaching the settings I use for the export below.

[image]
[image]

Maybe it will be useful. Here is what it looks like when I select both of the bottom parts.

[image]

Here is the mismatch I am getting when using the `.png`s exported.

[image]

[Here](https://svgshare.com/s/UDB) is the link to the svg itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are invisible objects in your design.

You can see some of them here:

[image]

After doing another check, selected just one object, and then I did *Edit > Select Same > Object Type*, I can see many others.  Many of these are duplicated several times one on top of the other.  To fix you should try to delete all these invisible objects.

[image]